# How to repeat a menu (ask for user input again) after switch got a wrong input character

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement

I have a menu, one of the options is to exit the program, but if the user types a character other than 1 2 3 4 5 6 it still exits the program or stops running it. I want that after input of a wrong character the menu apears again and the user can type again. I want this to hapen infinitly if the user types wrong characters infinitly.
Thanks a lot!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char opcao;


  printf("1 - \n"); 
  printf("2 -\n"); 
  printf("3 - \n"); 
  printf("4 - \n"); 
  printf("5 - \n"); 
  printf("6 - Terminar programa\n");  
  printf("Introduza a sua opcao:\n");
  scanf("%c",&opcao);

      switch(opcao){
    case'1':
      printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
      break;
    case'2':
      printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
      break;
    case'3':
      printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
      break;
    case'4':
      printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
      break;
    case'5':
      printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
      break;
    case'6':
      exit(0);
    default:
      printf("invalid input, please type again"); // this is what I want, but how?(now it would present the menu again...
      break;
      }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: do ... while loop? One of the first things in a C book

Comment: Hint:  The user may input incorrectly several times and you'll need to keep showing the menu.   So you want to put your switch statement in a loop.  Exit the loop when the input is correct.

Comment: A do while loop? @SteveWellens??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `do...while` loop so that your code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char opcao;


  printf("1 - \n"); 
  printf("2 -\n"); 
  printf("3 - \n"); 
  printf("4 - \n"); 
  printf("5 - \n"); 
  printf("6 - Terminar programa\n");  
  printf("Introduza a sua opcao:\n");
  do{ //loop
  scanf(" %c",&opcao); //discards blanks and reads the first non-whitespace character

      switch(opcao){
    case'1': 
    case'2':
    case'3':
    case'4':
    case'5':
  printf("Funcionalidade nao disponivel.");
   break;
    case'6':
      exit(0);
    default:
      printf("invalid input, please type again:"); // this is what I want, but how?(now it would present the menu again...
      }
  }while(opcao<'1' ||opcao>'6'); //loop until `opcao` less than '1' or greater than '6'

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If I hit a wrong input the output says the sentence invalid input, please type again: twice –

Comment: @LeonardoNunes , You did not copy my code correctly. Replace my `scanf` with your `scanf` and see the magic!

Answer (score 1):

I have given a sample code here. You can enhance it as per your need

```
#include <string.h>
int main (){
    char c, q=1;
    while ( q ){
        c=getchar ();
        switch (c){
            case '1':{} break;
            case '2': {printf ("quit the menu\n");q=0;}break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```